# Communication between WARs within the same tomcat server - JNDI vs REST API

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jndi

I have a requirement, where a front-end application (written in spring MVC) needs to communicate with another backend application. Both the applications are going to be WAR running within the same tomcat instance. For understanding purpose, lets name it frontend.war and backend.war.

I have gone through many posts across various forum, and found many different strategies, **some of them are as below:**

1) **Using EJB** - Ruled out, EJB's are maintenance overhead and we have no plan to create a dedicated EAR to accomplish this; because we have plan to add more different forntend wars (application modules) which will communicate to same backend.war.

2) **Using JNDI** : Looks promising, but it needs to have one war to know about the 'interface' being exposed by 2nd war, its signature. So, it is making it tightly coupled with each other. Future change in the service contract can become nightmare.

3) **Using REST API** : This looks an ideal approach, with only one caveat that the communication is over HTTP call, hence it could be slow.

Other approaches like common parentContext (in Spring). ContextSwitching within application does have their own issues.

I am getting inclined to use REST API approach for this solution; as it is cleaner and easy to maintain. Further the http protocol is mature and has lots of know-how available for future development.

**My query:**
A) Is it possible to make a tomcat aware that a particular webservice call is indeed a call on the application running same JVM/Server (kind of 'internal'); rather than an 'external' webservice call?

B) If I use url like 'http://localhost:8080/rest/...' (note that backend.war is not intended for external world, so a domain name is not needed) ; will it do the trick?

I am looking for an approach, which gives me performance of JNDI (communication within same JVM) and flexibility of REST (You can change anything, anytime as long as public URLs are intact).

Answer (score 1):

If you have thousand of war, maybe try the Enterprise service bus approach. WSO2 would be a good candidate. You could always change your entry point definition while keeping the backend intact.

Added benefit: your war can be deployed on multiple server and / or moved, but you keep only an entry point; only one address to change.

Comment: that still relies on REST HTTP tho. And from my experience WS02 is a right pain - maybe its improved recently but the version we use is dog slow, hangs frequently and needs restarting, buggy doesn;t remember your login credentials etc.

Comment: What's the call interface now for your war ? SOAP ?

Comment: Kindly elaborate, how WSO2 can enhance performance of service method call, vs REST approach. REST approach will also allow me to keep URLs intact. In fact this question is not about what infra I should use for app deployment; but rather if there can be an approach/trick which avoid (or at least) reduce the protocol layers within the war communication and making it a faster to interact with each other(compared to REST). I have JNDI approach, but I am loosing the flexibility of REST. I wish, I could use REST over jvm:// protocol.

Comment: @JFPicard - Right now we have not zero-ed upon the call interface. The question is for deciding that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jar file of the common functions, package them up as a dependcy to both projects - a service layer !

Alternatively, use rest and stick on different tomcat instances/servers - microservices!

Comment: 'Create a jar' - This approach would need to rebuild all the wars (note that there could be 1000s of them); if anything changes in common jar. Also, the jar would be maintained more like an API, where method signature, classes etc  can not be changed without breaking the wars. For rest alternative - we have the REST api war running within the same server instance with other wars (no point in running them separately).

Comment: there is a point to running them separately, they are independent that way, thats the ethos behind microservices and using containers.

Comment: I would love to do in that way, but I am thinking towards - if I can reap some benefit by running it into same instance, like able to call the service by http: //localhost... and expect TCP/IP to optimize the network I/O by recognizing that this call is going to land onto the same machine. It will not be a cross-domain call. Though, running a separate instance on the same machine should also have same result, but it will be one more tomcat instance to be maintained by support team.

Comment: @gyan yeah but thats not possible, unless you use jndi/ejbs as you already state. Is perfromance that important - won't a lot of it be cached anyway ?

Comment: I know that cache will help me to some extent with data static in nature, problem is that the backend is going to serve a lot of calls and data is going to change frequently; so the cache data will be short-lived. If nothing concrete found, I am going to stick with REST. Thanks for your insight on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use any "remote invocation" approach like Java RMI or CORBA. The latter applies also outside the Java world. Those have some benefits over others: they use TCP but not HTTP, therefore are lighter, serialize objects instead of creating new objects (like json or others). Additionally, I think RMI is simple to understand and use quickly.